# How weird can a ring spectrum be if all of its modules are free?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, stable-homotopy

Let $R$ be a ring spectrum. If $\pi_\ast(R)$ is a graded field, then all module spectra over $R$ are free. But I don't believe the converse holds. How badly can it fail?

I'm assuming that $R$ is at least an $A_3$ ring spectrum, and probably $A_\infty$ (I'm also interested in more highly-structured cases); if the answer depends on just how highly structured $R$ is, I'd find that interesting.

Note that if $\alpha \in \pi_\ast(R)$ is non-nilpotent, then the freeness of the localization $\alpha^{-1} R$ entails that $\alpha$ is a unit. So if all module spectra over $R$ are free, then $\pi_\ast(R)$ is a local ring of dimension 1. But $\pi_\ast(R)$ might have nonzero nilpotents as far as I can see.

**Question:** What is an example of a ring spectrum $R$ such that $\pi_\ast(R)$ has nonzero nilpotents and yet every module spectrum over $R$ is free?

Comment: Just a note, "free" here means you also allow suspensions of $R^n$'s; Lurie calls this quasi-free in his book. With the stronger notion obviously $R$ would be necessarily discrete.

Comment: @crystalline Good point! In fact, I'd be happy with an example where all modules are free in the even weaker sense that they are coproducts of invertible $R$-modules, although this doesn't quite make sense without some commutativity.

Comment: If any module over $R$ is free, then the cofiber $R/x$ is free for any $x\in\pi_*(R)$. If $x$ is not a unit, then $R/x$ is necessarily nontrivial. Now I am unable to come up with an example of $R$ and $x$ where $x$ is nonzero and $R/x$ is a nontrivial free module (I think this can't happen), but it would necessarily be weird. For example, note that $x^2$ acts trivially on $R/x$, thus also on the summand $R$, so your $R$ has the property that every element in homotopy is either a unit or has zero square.

Comment: Ah wait, I mixed something up, sorry! The statement is that if $R/x$ itself admits a ring structure, then $x$ acts trivially on it. In general this can fail even if $R$ is $\mathbb{E}_\infty$, as $R=\mathbb{S}$, $x=2$ shows. What I mixed up is that you need at least $\mathbb{E}_2$ to even get a module structure on $R/x$. So my second comment is nonsense and the first applies to $\mathbb{E}_2$ and higher only.

Comment: (I deleted the nonsensical comment since MO doesn't let you edit comments older than 5 minutes for some reason...)

Comment: @AchimKrause It seems to me that if $R$ is $E_1$, one can still define $R/x$ to be the cofiber of _right_ multiplication by $x$, and it should have a _left_ $R$-module structure.

Comment: You're absolutely right, that's the better way to say this. But to get any control over how $x$ acts on $R/x$ from the left then, I think you need an $E_2$ structure. Otherwise you don't have any reason to expect left multiplication with $x$ to act nilpotently on $R/x$. (and I guess something like a free associative algebra on multiple generators shows that this does indeed occur)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the notion of a **semisimple** ring spectrum, as studied by [Hovey and Lockridge](https://eudml.org/doc/130465). For such a ring spectrum, $E$, every module spectrum is projective, i.e. is a retract of a coproduct of suspensions of $E$. The homotopy groups $E_*$ of such spectra are characterized in Theorem 1.2 of this paper: $E_* \cong R_1 \times \dots \times R_n$ where $R_i$ is either a graded field $k$ or an exterior algebra $k[x]/(x^2)$ over a graded field with a unit in degree $3|x|+1$. Such rings $E_*$ are called **graded commutative $\Delta^1$-rings**, and clearly have plenty of non-zero nilpotent elements.

If $E$ is commutative, then $E$ is semisimple if and only if $E_*$ is a graded commutative $\Delta^1$-ring and for every factor ring of the form $k[x]/(x^2)$, we have $x\cdot \pi_*(C) \neq 0$ where $C$ is the cofiber of $x\cdot E$.

I'll finish by mentioning classic work of [Hopkins and Smith](http://hopf.math.purdue.edu/Hopkins-SmithJH/nilpII.sidebyside.pdf), that the OP is surely aware of but future readers might not be, that defines the **fields** of stable homotopy theory as ring spectra $E$ such that $E_*X$ is a free $E_*$-module for all spectra $X$, and that characterizes fields as spectra having the homotopy type of a wedge of suspensions of Morava $K$-theory $K(n)$ for some fixed $n$ and prime $p$.

Comment: Thanks David! I'm poring through this now!